# Angularjs "type" file is empty

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-service

I'm trying to upload a file but the "type" it appears empty.
I am following this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm

```
# Input file for upload
<input type="file" ng-file-model="myFile" />
<button type="button" ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
```

I'm checking the file in this way:

```
console.dir(file);
```

This is the result:

```
File {name: "myfile.csv", lastModified: 1525309436000, lastModifiedDate: Date 2015-02-09T15:09:43.000Z, size: 381, type: ""}
```

I believe the "type" being empty is causing error in the upload, because the function "error" in service shows "undefined".

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: That tutorial has a pretty large section of code. When I tried it, the type appeared to be dynamically detected. Could you show all of your code so we can see where you might have a difference?

Comment: Sorry, the file that is not being recognized in the upload is a .tab file with geospatial data. Csv file is recognize as "text/csv". I must specify the file type in input?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that .tab is not a recognized file format, so the type is empty. You might add a check on the file that looks for an empty type.

If empty type value:

1) Parse the filename for a ".xxx" and append that to the file object as the type ("text/xxx").

2) or set a default type whenever one isn't found, such as "text/plain".